# Finding the slope of the tangent with one point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am only given the curve $x(x^2+7)^{1/3}$(I have the derivative), and I am given that a tangent to the curve passes through the point $(1/13,0)$ (a point not on the curve). I have tried to find the slope of the external point and the corresponding point of the curve using point-slope form and the derivative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Find the equation of the tangent line at $x=c$. Then find which of those has the given point as a solution.

Comment: But the point is not on the curve. Except from the point given and the derivative of the curve, do I have anything to work on? I tried using different slope equations with the derivative but still have not yet  worked.

Comment: Find the equation of the tangent at $x=c$ where $c$ is free parameter. Then find which value of $c$ makes tangent to pass through required point.

Comment: Other option: solve $\frac{y(x)-y_{req}}{x-x_{req}}=y'(x)$ for $x$, where $x_{req}, y_{req}$ — given point, $y(x)$ — given curve. The problem transforms to cubic equation with inconvenient real root. Maybe, typo in problem statement.

Comment: Please do not use tags you do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

Write down the equation of the tangent line at an arbitrary (but unknown) point $x=c$. This equation will involve $x$, $y$, and the unknown $c$.

Write down an equation that expresses the fact that the point $(1/13,0)$ lies on this line.

Solve this latter equation for $c$.